# Downloaded simulators does not showing in Xcode 10.1 on macOS 10.15

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10.1, macos-catalina

I'm using `Xcode 10.1` and trying to add additional simulators for other iOS versions. From Preferences-> Components successfully download iOS v `9.0` & `10.1`

[image]

But while adding doesn't appear in the list. Tried by restarting Xcode, Mac and simulator still doesn't show.

[image: not showing in list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all solutions it still won't fix the issue. So the only way is to do:

1. Uninstalled all 3 versions of Xcode 10.1, 10.3 & 11 beta also deleted all downloaded simulators iOS 10.1, 9.0 from `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads`
2. Then install only Xcode 10.1 and download all required iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

Once can you please check settings in command line tools

Xcode -> preferences -> Location -> command line tools -> Xcode version

Please restart once again

Comment: CLI Xcode version also same 10.1 already tried this but won't work